# How to insert JSON object to SQL Server 2016 as nvarchar

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I want to insert a few JSON objects into my SQL Server 2016 table.

My table structure is as follows:

```
field           type            nullable   default
name          | nvarchar(max) | true     | Null
age           | nvarchar(max) | true     | Null
homeAddress   | nvarchar(max) | true     | Null
officeAddress | nvarchar(max) | true     | Null
```

I am using the following query to insert my data:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"name":"John Smith","age":32,"homeAddress":{"addr1":"123rd West Street, Willow Apt","addr2":"#55 Suite","zipCode":12345,"city":"Austin","state":"TX"},"officeAddress":{"addr1":"23rd West Street","addr2":"","zipCode":12345,"city":"Austin","state":"TX"}}';

INSERT INTO Employee 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (name nvarchar(50), 
          age int, 
          homeAddress nvarchar(max), 
          officeAddress nvarchar(max)
         );
```

However, only the value of `name` and `age` are populated in the table. Both `homeAddress` and `officeAddress` values are NULL.

What is wrong with my query? How can I insert a JSON object as nvarchar?

Comment: Seems like both `homeAddress` as well as `officeAddress` aren't just plain strings - but JSON objects themselves ...

Comment: Yes homeAddress and officeAddress are both json objects. I'm looking for tutorial to convert the objects to string, but still no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll admit I have no experience with JSON stuff in SQL Server 2016, but looking at this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server

It seems like adding `AS JSON` after your `NVARCHAR(max)` columns may be what you need:

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (name nvarchar(50), 
          age int, 
          homeAddress nvarchar(max) AS JSON, 
          officeAddress nvarchar(max) AS JSON
         );
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!