# SQL - Insert json array into multiple tables with identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, open-json

Here is the example json -

```json
     "Root Node - Type 1": {
                "Attributes": {
                    "Items": [
                        {
                            "A": {
                                "Value": "A1"
                            },
                            "B": {
                                "Value": "B1"
                            },
                            "C": {
                                "Value": "C1"
                            },
                            "D": {
                                "Value": "D1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "A": {
                                "Value": "A2"
                            },
                            "B": {
                                "Value": "B2"
                            },
                            "C": {
                                "Value": "C2"
                            },
                            "D": {
                                "Value": "D2"
                            }
                       }
            ]
    }
}
```

I need to insert A, B in table 1 and take the identity from table 1 and insert into table 2. Also, I need to insert C, D into table 3. Items here will be a large array. I am looking to bulk insert this data into tables. Any ideas?

Table structure -

```
 CREATE TABLE [Table 1](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [A] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [B] [varchar](15) NULL,
 [CreatedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL


 CREATE TABLE [Table 2](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Table1_Id] int,
 [CreatedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL

 CREATE TABLE [Table 3](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Table1_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [Value] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
```

Data 0 [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? DDL of your tables will help us help you.

Comment: I've written about [inserting multiple parents and children in the same procedure](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/05/17/insert-multiple-parents-with-multiple-children-in-a-single-stored-procedure/) in my blog, but that solution works with table valued parameters, not with Json. If you could [edit] your question with the DDL of the tables and give us a little bit better sample data, someone will probably be able to help you with that.

Comment: I am passing the json from azure logic app. I tried to insert this data in logic app. But, its taking a lot of time.So, I am trying to convert that to stored procedure instead. I tried to write a cursor to loop through the items. I want to know whats the most efficient way to insert here.

Comment: DDL, not images, please.

Comment: Updated with DDL

Comment: What gets inserted into column A of Table 1?  In the JSON there are 2 elements in the Items array which contain a key of "A".  Should the insert be 2 rows with the same value ("1")  into column A of Table 1?

Comment: You've done a good job posting DDL. I've edited your question to make the sample json a bit more clear, now if you could [edit] to show the results of the insert process - then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 

since SQL Server 2016 built-in functions exist for JSON data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323946/how-to-insert-json-object-to-sql-server-2016-as-nvarchar - i think this helps ;)